# What data type is best for sending through i2C (arduino)

Tags: types, arduino, i2c

hi i am developing a code to control multiple actuators and have these actuator return its position to the Master MCU. What data type would be best used on i2C? I am considering in using Strings or bytes for this.

Wifi Module - Receives command from web, sends commands to Master; Receives Position from Master
Master - sends commands to Nano(actuator controllers), receives position from Slave, send Position to Wifi 
Slave - receives commands, sends current position to Master

Comment: Probably byte...

Comment: different endianness could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Basically I2C could only transfer bytes, so there is no choise :-)

Defining you own protocol to transfer commands / receive positions ... would be the best way.

Strings a to heavy for such a task since you have to generate them, the amount of data to transfer is bigger and finally the decoding takes more time and memory.
The only advantage of a string transmission is a "human readability".

Comment: thanks, how about putting multiple command in a single packet. I heard that this is possible, where the receiving controller decodes the received command into multiple pieces.

Comment: SMBus on the other hand allows to send blocks.